# cin.ignore.get() causing my program to stuck on input

Tags: c++, cin

I have been instructed by my professor to use this code block below in my program.

```
void enter_to_continue() {
    cout << "Press enter to continue...";
    cin.ignore().get();
}
```

However, this code block does not work as expected. And no matter how many times I press `Return`, the program does not continue. Is this the proper way to implement it? (Also, while this may seem like a simple question, I have not found any other answers thus far.)

Compiled using g++ 11.4.0 on Ubuntu.

Comment: `cin.ignore().get();` is something I don't believe I've seen before. It would have to `ignore` one character and then `get` another. Two presses at the minimum  to exit, assuming the stream starts from empty. Just enter would get eaten by the ignore leaving the program to block on the `get`.

Comment: _"no matter how many times I press Return, the program does not continue"_ - That's odd. It does for me (after exactly one keystroke on any key followed by one Return). I'm assuming you have problems elsewhere in your program.

Comment: Which compiler and version are you using? Which os?

Comment: Everyone else in the class has had no problem with it, either. Is there some underlying C++ behavior that could cause this? Or is there another good way to implement a "Press enter to continue" ?

Comment: @AlanBirtles added to the question.

Comment: You should be able to get almost what you want just with `get` and a check to ensure what you got really was the user hitting enter. I'd just throw down a `cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n')`: ignore everything up until a newline. That'll always work.

Comment: We need a bit more context, I think. Could you throw together a quick [mre], complete with the exact input you use to get failure, and add it to the question?

Comment: 1. Is is possible that `std::cin` is in a failed state? 2. Trusting the user to press Enter without typing anything else is not robust. My version of this function calls `std::getline(std::cin, s)` in a loop. Inside the loop, it trims whitespace from string `s`, and then checks that `s` is empty. The loop stops when `s` is empty. Otherwise, the function displays a message saying to, "Press Enter on a blank line...", and keeps looping.

Comment: Are you using g++/linux while others are using msvc/windows?